# How to point custom domain to VM instance

Tags: nginx, redirect, server, google-compute-engine, gcloud

These are my dns records:

```
Name | Type | TTL | Target
        A    3600   185.199.108.153
        A    3600   185.199.109.153
        A    3600   185.199.110.153
        A    3600   185.199.111.153
www   CNAME  3600   pushp1997.github.io
        A    3600   34.71.130.252
```

Here, the first 5 entries are to open my static github pages site.

The last entry is the ip address of my VM instance on GCloud.

These are my nginx server settings:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name pushp.ml;
  location /linkedin {
    return 302 https://in.linkedin.com/in/pushp-vashisht;
  }
}
```

Now, if I try `34.71.130.252/linkedin` it redirects me to `https://in.linkedin.com/in/pushp-vashisht`.

But, when I try `pushp.ml/linkedin` it shows a 404 page of Github Pages.

How do I make `pushp.ml/linkedin` to redirect to `https://in.linkedin.com/in/pushp-vashisht`?

---

Edit:

On running dig command:

```
$ dig pushp.ml

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> pushp.ml
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36898
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pushp.ml.                      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pushp.ml.               3600    IN      A       185.199.109.153
pushp.ml.               3600    IN      A       185.199.110.153
pushp.ml.               3600    IN      A       34.71.130.252
pushp.ml.               3600    IN      A       185.199.108.153
pushp.ml.               3600    IN      A       185.199.111.153

;; Query time: 431 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 17 17:13:57 EDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117
```

In answer section we can see that ip addresses of github pages server as well as my vm instance are there.

Comment: Whos the DNS service? And by the look of it, it will most likely send the request to GitHub by default because you've prefixed the record with `www`. Try prefixing the last IP with `@`. `@  A  3600  34.71.130.252`.

Comment: This looks like a good way but using sub-domain might have much cleaner aesthetics. I.E.  `linkedin  A  3600  34.71.130.252`. That would translate to `linkedin.pushp.ml`

Comment: Hi @PraveenPremaratne I am using Freenom's DNS service, when I try to prefix the last IP with @ on freenom's portal, it says wildcard @ is not allowed, have to use blank field instead.

Comment: I tried your subdomain way of doing the same and it works perfectly. Thanks! @PraveenPremaratne